# Azcopy psts getting error 404 attempting to upload Need to download lower version

Tags: azure, pst, azcopy

Getting Error parsing destination location "https://f47hr7hfh74hf4747fh74fh74.blob.core.windows.net/ingestiondata": Failed to validate destination: One or more errors occurred. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. The specified resource does not exist.

I have searched they are having issues in their latest version. Can Any one help me or send me link for download Lower version of azcopy tool. I am using 5.1.0 version.

Comment: @Nick Lynn Any Help

Comment: You need to provide more details in your question as to what exactly you're trying to do and how are you executing AzCopy. You also mentioned that other people are having issues with the latest version. Please share the links for those as well. Do update your question instead of providing details in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 5.0.0, worked for me:
http://az635501.vo.msecnd.net/azcopy-5-0-0/MicrosoftAzureStorageTools.msi

Comment: That URL should be all over Microsoft's missing helpfiles on this issue. 5.1 is completely broken for PST ingestion.